# formatting of a date in the format of mmm yy to yymm using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to convert a date in xslt to another format.
the incoming data is "Feb 18" and the formatted date should be "1802". I know i need to parse the data first into a datetime and then convert it. but it is not recognizing the format.

```
<xsl:variable name="dt" as="xs:date" select="xs:date(period)"/>
perio><xsl:value-of select="$dt"/></perio>
```

Thanks to help.
Ashley

Comment: So where is your date (component?) format defined exactly? If you want to construct an `xs:date` you need a day, a month and a year.  Not sure whether the `18` in your sample is part of a year or is the day of a month, but use string and/or regular expression to extract the components and then convert your verbal month representation to a number with e.g. `index-of(('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', ..., 'Dec', 'Feb')`

Comment: You need to tell us whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. It's a waste of our time if we give you a solution for the wrong version.

Comment: hi guys, I am using xslt1.0. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<xsl:variable name="t" select="tokenize($in)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$t[2] || 
   format-integer(index-of(('Jan','Feb,'Mar'...), $t[1]), '00')"/>
```

Comment: I wasted my time by giving you an XSLT 3.0 solution. (Unless you can be persuaded to move into the 21st century, of course). Next time, if you're using an old version of the language, please say so.